# how to identify wrong/bad repo in my linux machine?

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, rpm, repository

dear friends and colleges,

I want to share with you the following issue , and I am sure this important to some of the colleges here

I want to verify the that all repo in my linux machine are ok

so we run the command - **yum repolist** as the following

we can see the errors about one of the repo

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
file:///var/repoha/bility/h5th5th54/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /var/repoha/bility/h5th5th54/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.
file:///var/repoha/bility/h5th5th54/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /var/repoha/bility/h5th5th54/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.
Storage                                                                                                                                                      | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
Storage/group_gz                                                                                                                                             | 4.9 kB  00:00:00
Storage/primary_db                                                                                                                                           |  29 kB  00:00:00
local                                                                                                                                                                 | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
local/group_gz                                                                                                                                                        | 136 kB  00:00:00
local/primary_db                                                                                                                                                      | 3.6 MB  00:00:00
repo id                                                         repo name                                                                                                              status
bility                                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo) - bility                                                     0
Storage                                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo) - Storage                                                    37
local                                                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo) - Local                                                            4,620
repolist: 4,657
```

so in order to verify if repo are ok or not we want to check the status of $?

```
[root@trump yum.repos.d]# echo $?
0
```

but we get 0

why we get "0" ? in-spite repo isn't correct?

***my question is how to identify wrong/bad repo in my linux machine ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside my Ansible roles I use `check-update --refresh` - as an option to the `dnf` command, but the same idea should apply to `yum`.

`yum` may not have the `--refresh` option.  Instead, run `yum clean expire-cache` and then `yum check-update`.

The exit status (`$?`) of `check-update` is equal to  `0` on success, `100` if updates are available.  Any other value would indicate a failure.  Usually, though I guess not always, this will indicate a problem reading a repo.  For my purposes, this is sufficient.  For example, if I disconnect from the network and run that command right now, it is returning an exit status of `1`.

More specifically, my Ansible role is installing a new repo and wants to verify that one repo.  E.g. to check whether the repo `bility` is functional and it's metadata can be read, I use a command like `dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=bility --refresh check-update`.

Comment: so you say that we cant identify bad repo or wrong repo ?

Comment: any way we not use unsible , so we are stuck with this un answered problem

Comment: do you mean just to run the "yum check-update" ?

Comment: we have redhat 7 so --refresh. isnt there , but really yum check-update  is answer my quastion when repo is wrong we get $? = 255 and when repo is ok then we get 0

Comment: see my update in my quastion , when we do yum check-update --refresh , we got incorrect usage

Comment: @yael updated with the yum equivalent.

Comment: so what the diff between yum clean expire-cache to yum clean all ?

Comment: @yael https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-working_with_yum_cache

Comment: so we can use also the yum clean all and yum check-update ?

Comment: @yael probably, I suspect it tends not to make a difference in practice. I personally was anxious about removing "any cached packages from the system", because I might want them later, to save network bandwidth.